# Characterization of split exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

I have seen quoted here in a few places that having a sequence:
$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$ with maps $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ is split exact if and only if there exist maps $h: C \rightarrow B$ and $i: B \rightarrow C$ such that
$$\begin{align*} g \circ f = 0\\
g \circ h = Id_C\\ i \circ f = Id_A\\ h \circ g + f \circ i = Id_B. \end{align*}$$

The only thing I'm having trouble seeing is how the last equation is implied by the sequence being split exact, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence is split exact, that means that (up to isomorphism) we have $B=A\oplus C$ with $f$ the inclusion and $g$ the projection.  Taking $h$ and $i$ to be the other inclusion and other projection, then $$(h\circ g+f\circ i)(a,c)=h(g(a,c))+f(i(a,c))=h(c)+f(a)=(0,c)+(a,0)=(a,c)$$ for any $(a,c)\in B$.  Thus $h\circ g+f\circ i=Id_B$,

Comment: But if $f$ and $g$ are fixed and we don't know that they are the inclusion and projection then how do we know? Also, even if we knew that they were the inclusion and projection we can still find $h$ and $i$ that allows the splitting lemma to work but I don't think that equation would be forced. Couldn't $h \circ g + f \circ i$ be some automorphism map on $B$ that is not the identity?

Comment: We _do_ know $f$ and $g$ are the inclusion and projection; that's what it means for the sequence to be split exact (at least by my definition; if you have a different definition you need to say what it is).  The assertion is that _there exist_ $h$ and $i$ with the stated properties, so we get to choose what they are, so we can choose them to be the other inclusion and other projection.